# Equivalent to the htop command on Windows

Tags: windows, htop

I installed an nginx server on Windows, then ran it and tested it by accessing it on the local host. 
However I want to see more details which I can see on a Linux environment when running the `htop` command (which gives details on the no. of worker processes running on the nginx server).

Does such command also exists on Windows?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Microsoft Sysinternals Suite](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062) can do what you need, as quite easily found via the search engine of your choice.

Specifically [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx)

Comment: procexp doesn't have a cli viewer does it?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. But have a look at [this page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer#learn-more)

Comment: The diagram writes top CPU user process, just what I needed.

Comment: I remember sysinternals from before they were owned by Microsoft and it was just a labor of love for their developer who built them and gave them all away free.  They're great tools.

Comment: @thomasrutter I think they made money by running Winternals, which made commercial tools such as NTFS drivers for other platforms (e.g. DOS), password reset tools (similar to chntpw), disk partitioning tools (similar to PartitionManager or GParted) and some recovery tools for WinPE among other things. I recall their tools being rather expensive, in the hundreds or even thousands of dollars for the "Administrator's Pak". But the Sysinternals branch of tools has always been free as far as I recall, and basically served as their thanks to their customers and to the Windows community at large.

Comment: Another interesting bit of trivia: Winternals/Sysinternals was run by Mark Russinovich, who famously wrote (writes?) the Windows Internals series of textbooks/reference manuals and has even wrote fiction thriller novels (Zero Day and its sequels). He was brought on as a Microsoft employee with the acquisition and still works at Microsoft as far as I know.

Answer (score 34):

You can try htop-alternative for windows - NTop https://github.com/Nuke928/NTop

You can install it with

```
choco install ntop.portable
```

or with

```
scoop install ntop
```

Comment: This! If my CPU is burning and I'd like to know why - I need a CLI tool accessible from SSH session, not a GUI tool that requires me to RDP into the server first. And you can install it via `winget` which is a built-n package manager for Windows `winget install ntop`

Comment: This is lovely. I don't prefer working in PowerShell but when I do I'd like to be able to do as much as possible in the terminal.

Answer (score 6):

Nothing beats the look and familiar functionality of **btop++ for Windows** by [aristocratos/btop4win](https://github.com/aristocratos/btop4win). Plus, it's a breeze to install with just one `scoop install btop` command.

Answer (score 3):

Everything is built into Windows. Just go to task manager and click the different tabs. Especially the details tab to see processes etc.

You can also simply type "Get-Process" into PowerShell.

Here is more detail: [Using the Get-Process Cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-powershell-1.0/ee176855(v=technet.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: Be aware that some shops run non-gui.

Comment: be aware, htop has SEVERAL features, that the Windows Task Manager does not have. Some examples: Setting I/O-Priority, Sending different Signals to a process other than SIGTERM and SIGKILL, Proper filtering, Tree View, Showing kernel-threads, showing process environment, list file locks. Selecting multiplce processes and applying the same settings simultaniously, selecting threads at all (e.g. to change priorities). (No exhaustive list of features I use htop for among other things, but comments are limited in size)

Answer (score 0):

`Task Manager` could be a helpful option.

Shortcut : `Ctrl+Alt+Delete` and select Task Manager.

Comment: how does this address the question?

Answer (score 0):

[process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer)  or [process hacker](https://processhacker.sourceforge.io/)